# Display a jpg image on a JPanel

Tags: java, image, jpanel

What would be the most appropriate image type to display a jpg image (loaded from a local folder) on a JPanel?

Cheers.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("image/pic1.jpg");
JLabel label = new JLabel("", image, JLabel.CENTER);
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
panel.add( label, BorderLayout.CENTER );
```

Answer (score 7):

You could use a javax.swing.ImageIcon and add it to a JLabel using setIcon() method, then add the JLabel to the JPanel.

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably use an ImageIcon and set it on a JLabel which I'd add to the JPanel.

[Here's](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) Sun's docs on the subject matter.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a Canvas that I add to the JPanel, and draw the image on the Canvas.
But Canvas is a quite heavy object, sine it is from awt.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use

```
ImageIcon background = new ImageIcon("Background/background.png");
JLabel label = new JLabel();
label.setBounds(0, 0, x, y);
label.setIcon(background);

JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(null);
panel.add(label);
```

if your working with a absolut value as layout.