# How to open an image from JMenu in Java?

Tags: java, swing, awt, jmenu

I'm trying to open an image when the user clicks a certain button in my JMenu. I have to configure the m5 and m6 from this code:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Menu extends JMenuBar implements ActionListener {
    Interface map;

    JMenu m1;
    JMenu m2;
    JMenu m3;
    JMenu m4;
    JMenu m5;
    JMenu m6;
    JMenuItem m12;
    JMenuItem m121;
    JMenuItem m122;
    JMenuItem m123;

    JMenuItem m222;
    JMenuItem m331;
    JMenuItem m332;
    JMenuItem m441;
    JMenuItem m442;
    JMenuItem m551;
    JMenuItem m661;

    public Menu(Interface map) {
        super();
        this.map = map;
        m1 = new JMenu("Nouvelle grille");
        m2 = new JMenu("Solutionner");
        m3 = new JMenu("Générer une grille");
        m4 = new JMenu("Fonctions supplémentaires");
        m5 = new JMenu("Edition");
        m6 = new JMenu("Aide");
        m121 = new JMenuItem("Niveau fort");
        m122 = new JMenuItem("Niveau moyen");
        m123 = new JMenuItem("Niveau faible");
        m12 = new JMenuItem("Sélectionner dans une liste");
        m121.addActionListener(this);
        m122.addActionListener(this);
        m123.addActionListener(this);
        m12.addActionListener(this);
        m222 = new JMenuItem("Vider la Grille");
        m222.addActionListener(this);
        m1.add(m222);
        m331 = new JMenuItem("Afficher la solution");
        m331.addActionListener(this);
        m2.add(m331);
        m332 = new JMenuItem("Cacher la solution");
        m332.addActionListener(this);
        m2.add(m332);
        m332.setEnabled(false);
        m441 = new JMenuItem("Copier grille dans le presse-papier");
        m441.addActionListener(this);
        m4.add(m441);
        m442 = new JMenuItem("Imprimer Grille+Solution");
        m442.addActionListener(this);
        m4.add(m442);
        m551 = new JMenuItem("Annuler déplacement");
        m551.addActionListener(this);
        m5.add(m551);
        m661 = new JMenuItem("Règlements");
        m661.addActionListener(this);
        m6.add(m661);
        m3.add(m121);
        m3.add(m122);
        m3.add(m123);
        m3.addSeparator();
        m3.add(m12);
        this.add(m1);
        this.add(m2);
        this.add(m3);
        this.add(m4);
        this.add(m5);
        this.add(m6);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

        map.ecouteur.carre = null;
        if (evt.getSource() == m121) {
            // map.cherchernouvellesgrilles();
            map.supanel.selection(3);
        } else if (evt.getSource() == m122) {
            // map.testersinouvellegrille();
            map.supanel.selection(2);
        } else if (evt.getSource() == m123) {
            map.supanel.selection(1);
        } else if (evt.getSource() == m222) {
            map.supanel.vidergrille();
            // map.supanel.cherchernouvellesgrilles();
        } else if (evt.getSource() == m331) {
            if (map.supanel.solutionnergrille()) {
                m331.setEnabled(false);
                m332.setEnabled(true);
            }
        } else if (evt.getSource() == m332) {
            map.supanel.cachersolution();
            m331.setEnabled(true);
            m332.setEnabled(false);
        } else if (evt.getSource() == m661) {
            // Image Should Be Here
            m661.setEnabled(true);
        }

        else if (evt.getSource() == m441) {
            if (map.getSudoku().getTableaufinal() != null) {
                ecriturepressepapier(map.getSudoku().getTableaufinal());
            } else {
                ecriturepressepapier(map.getSudoku().getGrille());
            }
        }

        else if (evt.getSource() == m442) {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Aperçu avant Impression");
            frame.setSize(new Dimension(305, 640));
            Fond supanelreponse1 = new Fond(map.map, map);
            Fond supanelreponse2 = new Fond(map.map, map);
            supanelreponse1.impressionapartirdetableau(map.sudoku.grille);
            if (map.supanel.solutionnergrille()) {
                System.out.println("GRILLE");
                map.sudoku.afficher(map.sudoku.grille);
                System.out.println("REPONSE");
                map.sudoku.afficher(map.sudoku.tableaufinal);
                supanelreponse2
                        .impressionapartirdetableau(map.sudoku.tableaufinal);
                // CONTENTPANEL
                JPanel contentPanel = (JPanel) frame.getContentPane();
                contentPanel.setLayout(null);

                supanelreponse1.setBounds(0, 0, 300, 300);
                contentPanel.add(supanelreponse1);

                supanelreponse2.setBounds(0, 301, 300, 300);
                contentPanel.add(supanelreponse2);

                frame.setContentPane(contentPanel);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                MPanelPrinter mp = new MPanelPrinter(contentPanel);
                mp.print();
                map.supanel.cachersolution();
                frame.dispose();
            }
        }
        map.requestFocus();
    }

    public void ecriturepressepapier(int[][] tableau) {
        String temp = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < tableau.length + 2; i++) {
            temp += "#";
        }
        temp += "\n";

        for (int i = 0; i < tableau.length; i++) {
            temp += "#";
            for (int e = 0; e < tableau[i].length; e++) {
                if (tableau[i][e] != 0) {
                    temp += Integer.toString(tableau[i][e]);
                } else {
                    temp += " ";
                }
            }
            temp += "#\n";
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < tableau.length + 2; i++) {
            temp += "#";
        }
        map.getMpp().setClipboardContents(temp);
    }
}
```

For example, when the user clicks on the m6 JMenu, an image have to open. I guess that I have to insert the code at this place :

```
else if(evt.getSource()==m661){
    // Image Should Be Here
    m661.setEnabled(true);
}
```

I can't understand how to do it and I'd like to know what are the map.supanel things? It's seems that the action is triggered by them but I can't understand where they come from.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `map` is an instance of the class `Interface`, `supanel` will be defined there, although I suspect it's a reference to a sub-panel.  You should be able to determine which package it's in from your IDE and check its API.  As for displaying an image when "Règlements" is clicked, there are a wide variety of swing and awt tutorials on the internet and Google will translate almost all of them to French for you.

Comment: Thanks for that! I've been sorting the code for quite a bit now and I'm starting to understand(slowly)! I found where the subpanel is and now I have to implement the code for the image. I've tried all pieces of code I found on the internet but nothing works. What is the simpliest code for opening an image in java?

Comment: I know for sure that the code has to be here:else if(evt.getSource()==m661){
    // Image Should Be Here
    m661.setEnabled(true); }   because when I try for example to print a message it works. However, I can't get an image to display!

Comment: try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242581/display-a-jpg-image-on-a-jpanel).

Comment: I just tried this answer. Now the program compiles but when I click on the desired menu tab, nothing happens! :(

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) One way to get images for an example, is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556).

Comment: are you trying to open an image file or display the image on your window?