# Error when I try to put an ImageIcon in Java

Tags: java, swing, icons, label

I tried to put a simple icon in a JPanel formatted with the BoxLayout.

```
    JPanel panel_4 = new JPanel();
    contentPane.add(panel_4, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel_4.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel_4, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

    ImageIcon seven= new ImageIcon("‪C:\\Users\\alewe\\workspace\\SlotMachine\\Lucky_Seven-128.png");

    JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel(seven);
    panel_4.add(lblNewLabel_1);
```

When I ran the code it gave me the error "`Some characters cannot be mapped using "Cp1252" character encoding`", I saved by `UTF-8`, now it starts but I can't see the icon.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242581/display-a-jpg-image-on-a-jpanel) might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe if you use `setIcon` will help you:

```
ImageIcon seven= new ImageIcon("‪C:\\Users\\alewe\\workspace\\SlotMachine\\Lucky_Seven-128.png");
JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel();
//Set your icon to your label
lblNewLabel_1.setIcon(seven);
panel_4.add(lblNewLabel_1);
```

You can read more about icons [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html)

Answer (score 0):

you will need a inputstream to read the picture. use it like this:

```
File f = new File("filepath");
        InputStream in=new FileInputStream(f);
            if (in != null) {
                ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(in));
                label.setIcon(imageIcon);
            } else {
                LOG.debug("No icon found...");
            }
```

Comment: Thanks , it works , even i prefer the setIcon answer :)

Comment: if i dont use the inputstream i always get the error you did. just copied the accepted answer and error pops up